# Preload all tabs when shiny app loads

Tags: r, tabs, shiny, r-markdown

Below is a simple reproducible app.  I have two tabs. Tab 1 displays a chart while Tab 2 displays a chart and table.

I have also a download button in the side bar and an Rmd document.

The question is, the resulting html page I want to download fails unless I select Tab 2.  When I select Tab 2 the download works fine even if I go back to Tab 1 before downloading. Obviously this is due in part to the reactive element on Tab 2.

However, I want the download to work whether or not I visit Tab 2.  In other words when the app loads I can just click the download button and the resulting html page will contain the charts and the table from both tabs.

Is there a way to preload Tab 2?  As you can see, I have tried the outputOptions function with suspendWhenHidden = FALSE but it doesn't seen to work.

Any help please?

**Shiny:**

```
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)


data(mtcars)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Preload Plots"),

  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("down")
  ),


  mainPanel(
    fluidRow(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Panel 1",
                 plotOutput("plot1")
                 ),
        tabPanel("Panel 2",
                 uiOutput("selectList"),
                 plotOutput("plot2"),
                 tableOutput("tbl")
                 )
      )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output){


  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(mtcars$cyl)
    })


  output$selectList <- renderUI({
    selectInput("selectionBox", "Select Cyl Size", unique(mtcars$cyl), selected = 4)
  })

  cylFun <- reactive(
     mtcars[mtcars$cyl == input$selectionBox, c("mpg", "wt")]
  )

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(cylFun())
    })

  outputOptions(output, "plot2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)


  output$tbl <- renderTable(
    table(cylFun())
  )

  outputOptions(output, "tbl", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  output$down <- renderUI({
    downloadButton("downloadPlots", "Download Plots")
  })

  output$downloadPlots <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "plots.html",

    content = function(file){
      params = list(p2 = cylFun())
      render("plots.Rmd", html_document(), output_file = file)
    }
  )

}


shinyApp(ui, server
```

**Rmarkdown:**

````
---
title: "plots"
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo = FALSE}

barplot(mtcars$cyl)

```

```{r, echo = FALSE}

plot(params$p2)
knitr::kable(params$p2)

```
````

Thanks
Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, `suspendWhenHidden` seems to be the key. The problem is that the Rmd rendering needs `cylFun` to have a value, and `cylFun` depends on the `selectionBox` input value you create with `renderUI`. You have the `suspendWhenHidden` option for the plot and table, but these cannot be calculated without `selectionBox`, and the markdown works without them.

So just add

```
  outputOptions(output, "selectList", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
```

and it should work. You can also remove the `outputOptions` for the table and plot on tab 2.

Comment: You're a star! I was just fixating on the tables. Doooh. What you have said makes perfect sense and works. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose the next question is can all values on selectList be charted in the report for Tab 2 without specifically selecting them?

Comment: You mean doing the plot for all values of cyl, not just the one selected on the second tab? Just iterate over them in the Rmd file, and use the full version of the data frame instead of the filtered one passed in as a `param`.

Comment: I'm using `outputOptions(suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` to render a plot on a `hidden` tab. However, now the `updateSelectizeInput()` an in `observeEvent` runs, but the actual `selectizeInput` never update on the client. I've set a high `priority` on the `observeEvent` with no luck. The only way to get `updateSelectizeInput` to run successfully is to remove `outputOptions()`

Answer (score 0):

An easily available hack to load all tabs using your downloadButton renderUI.
Using **req** keyword as below. This will load all the outputs and all tabs will be loaded  and then appear.

```
 output$down <- renderUI({
    req(plot1,selectList,plot2,tbl)
    downloadButton("downloadPlots", "Download Plots")
  })
```

Enjoy!